# Altruist badge: necessary and sufficient conditions?

Tags: support, badges

Out of curiosity: I spent a bounty on sb else' question and have yet not got the Atruist badge. How come?

Comment: How long ago?  It can easily take a day to get it, I've found

Comment: @Mary Initiation more than a week ago; expiration many days ago.

Comment: This is because you didn’t personally and manually award the bounty. You placed it and let the deadline pass, so the system automatically awarded half the bounty on your behalf. To get the badge, you need to personally click the “award bounty to this answer” button. More here:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for/67399#67399 .

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I lurked a bit through your reputation history and found the bounty you awarded, which is [here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/86717/most-important-modern-contemporary-essays-on-free-will).

As you can see, the bounty has been awarded to the *answer* of this question, not the question itself, which is probably why there was no badge awarded for it.